# Python: Memory error running executables from within script on Amaxon AWS

Tags: python, linux, memory, amazon-ec2, cloud

I am trying to move a series of python scripts from a hpc cluster to the amazon cloud.  I have an executable that needs to be called from within the script.  I always used os.system to do this, but it would not work when running in the cloud and i think it may have been deprecated.  At any rate, it doesn't seem to be the preferred way to handle this, so I switched to subprocess.call.  The command line I give works if I type it at the shell prompt:

```
$needle  -outfile=../test.txt_results/Output/Needlescores/OG5_126737_Am_ac_Acasneedle.txt -asequence=../test.txt_results/Temp/Am_ac_Acasseq1.fasta -bsequence=../test.txt_results/Temp/Am_ac_Acasseq2.fasta -gapopen=10 -gapextend=0.5
```

and it works if I open a python interpreter and use the subprocess.call:

```
>>> call('needle  -outfile=../test.txt_results/Output/Needlescores/OG5_126737_Am_ac_Acasneedle.txt -asequence=../test.txt_results/Temp/Am_ac_Acasseq1.fasta -bsequence=../test.txt_results/Temp/Am_ac_Acasseq2.fasta -gapopen=10 -gapextend=0.5',shell = True)
```

But, if I run it from within my script I get an error:

```
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

I went into the script and changed the call to call('ls', shell = True) and it still gave me the same error so I don't think it has anything to do with my executable using too much memory.

```
  File "/home/ubuntu/Scripts/Taxon/__init__.py", line 541, in runneedle
    child = subprocess.call('ls', shell = True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1143, in _execute_child
    self.pid = os.fork()
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

I looked around for people who have had similar errors, and there was one very technical (to my inexperienced eyes) answer about forks - but it didn't seem specific enough to help me and I don't know how I would handle something like this, especially in an EC2 instance.

Has anyone had this problem - and found a solution - or does anyone have advice for someone fairly new to working in linux and in the cloud?

Comment: Start your debugging with something simpler: `subprocess.call(['ls'])`. If that works then change your call to `subprocess.call(['needle', '-outfile=...', '-asequence=...', '-gaopen=10', ...])`, which is *the preferred way in any case*. If it doesn't work then first have a look at how much memory you have free when you want to invoke, and how many open file handles you have.

Comment: Thanks, Nitzan.  I had tried something similar to that with no luck - but it turns out the problem was with the instance of the cloud.  I was trying to get things working on their free tier before committing to paying for it and either there was too little memory available or they don't allow processes to be called from within other processes.  I moved to one of their larger options and it is working! Cheers!